# Batch file (.bat) to move files to a new folder (files selected using sqlplus)

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I am new to batch scripting. I was told to create a batch script that will be able to seletc the files in a table in move the files to a new folder indicated in table2. Below are the steps expected from the script:

1. select the name/s of the file from table1 with processflg = 1 (can be multiple files)
2. check if the file is existing in the local folder (current folder)
3. select the new folder in table2 with name = filename from #1
4. if new folder is not existing create the folder
5. if new folder is already existing move the file
6. update the processflg in table2 with value = 1

I am still reading some stuff regarding batch scripting to help me with this stuff. Currently i was just able to perform a simple select with my sample .bat file. Looking forward for your ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add that .bat file code to the question (and select the text after pasting and press Ctrl-K to display it properly), it'll be helpful for those who only know batch file syntax.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm i have update the question, not sure if i did it correctly. I just want to ask, is this task that complex?

Comment: 1. This task seems simple. 2. Instead of editing the question's title add the actual code of the sample .bat file with `simple select` you've mentioned.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. I suggest you look up spooling and string concatenation for sqlplus and how to move files from a batch file, give it your best attempt, and then come back when you've got a specific part you're stuck on.

Comment: Thanks,  i have seek assistance from my friend and upon further explanation on what needs to be done, i was able to complete this task.I used spool and put_line to generate the batch file.